# How to create int list from string in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, stored-procedures, int

I have a mysql stored procedure which accepts a string, which is a list of integers. I would like to search in this string using the msql ,,in (),, .

Example:
string parameter = "1,2,3,4,5,6";

select * from table where table.id in (parameter);

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can use `find_in_set`:

```
select *
from table
where find_in_set(id, parameter);
```

Note, however, that the above will restrict optimizer from using index if any on the id column.

If you can, after checking for SQL injection etc. in your application, concatenate it to the SQL like this, that will perform better:

```
"select * from table where id in (" + parameter + ")"
```

and use that to execute.

Comment: I was also doing it with find_in_set exactly like you suggested, but it only returns one row, it might be because of find_in_set behaviour or casting string to int, which stops at first non int character.

Calling SQL directly from the app is a possible solution. But if possible I would prefer stored procedure.